# 3ds Max Strap / bandage animation problem

Tags: 3d, 3ds-max, maya

Below is the image of what I am trying to achieve. My client wants me to create animations of character applying multiple straps or bandage in various ways.

I've tried Normal rigging / spline IK / Squashy rig and it gives poor (Jitter in animation + texture stretch + it doesn't conform properly).

Now I am trying to use path deform to show strap move along the path which I think seems like a good solution as far as animation goes but now again I cant figure out how to conform this strap to leg 3D model while it moves along the path. (rotation + twist values are not working at all).

I'll appreciate any help.

[image: spline]

Answer (score 0):

My 3DS knowledge is no longer current - I can tell you how I'd approach it in modo and odds are high there's a direct equivalent workflow in 3DS:

I'd probably use UV transforms - so make the bandage flat, apply a UV transform targeting the UV's of the foot/ankle mesh, and you can then animate the degree to which (percentage) the UV transform is being applied, and that should have the effect of wrapping it onto the foot/ankle mesh.

Alternatively, you could move points using the foot/ankle mesh as a background constraint, and store that point translation as a morph map, and again, animate the percentage application of the morph map, which again would get you the bandage being wrapped.

Comment: I am not sure about UV method even if Max has it , I am sure It cant be animated just like 3ds Max loft which gives you manual control over twist but pointless in my case.

I don't understand the alternative method you mentioned.